# Context is lost when embedding views inside of views

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember 0.9.8.1 and having an issue with nested views not retaining the context of their parents properly. I'm trying to follow this recent gist by Tom Dale on how this behavior was changed in 0.9.8, but it's not working for me: https://gist.github.com/2494968

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/Zngar/1/

Am I doing something wrong? Or should this be filed as a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working in your case here: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/Zngar/3/

`number` is an attribute of the containing view. It is not forwarded unless you do it explicitly as demonstrated in the fiddle.

Scope forwarding works with controllers, when you use outlets. View is bound to a controller, and contained views, when not having any controller, fallback to their parent's one.